# Simple problem with mod_rewrite in the Fat Free Framework

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, fat-free-framework

I am trying to setup and learn the Fat Free Framework for PHP. 
http://fatfree.sourceforge.net/

It's is fairly simple to setup and I am running it on my machine using MAMP.

I was able to get the 'hello world' example running just fin:

```
require_once 'path/to/F3.php';
F3::route('GET /','home');
    function home() {
        echo 'Hello, world!';
    }
F3::run();
```

But when I try to add in the second part, which has two routes:

require_once 'F3/F3.php';

```
F3::route('GET /','home');
function home() {
    echo 'Hello, world!';
}

F3::route('GET /about','about');
function about()
{
    echo 'About Us.';
}

F3::run();
```

I get a 404 error if I try the second URL: /about

Not sure why one of the `mod_rewrite` commands would be working and not the other.

Below is my `.htaccess` file:

```
# Enable rewrite engine and route requests to framework
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L,QSA]

# Disable ETags
Header Unset ETag
FileETag none

# Default expires header if none specified (stay in browser cache for 7 days)
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A604800
</IfModule>
```

Comment: @DC No luck, I'm not sure where to even mess around to fix it.

Comment: New Fat-Free site: http://bcosca.github.com/fatfree/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So my friend actually helped me out with this issue.  I ran into the exact same problem, but basically I'm using MAMP also and have all my Fat Free files within a `fatfree` dir within htdocs of MAMP.

The solution is you need to mod the `RewriteBase` to point to `/[dirname]/` instead of just `/` and then change `RewriteRule` to `/[dirname]/index.php`.

My .htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /fatfree/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* /fatfree/index.php [L,QSA]
```

After that's set, you can follow the example in the Fat Free doc exactly and it'll work like a charm.  This stumped me for a while and this was all it needed.  Also, if you're using MAMP, edit the `httpd.conf` file in `/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache` and be sure to alter the following:

```
<Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Basically change `None` to `All`.

Comment: Thanks I tried all that but still no luck. `/` works but not `/anything`

Comment: Did the trick for me.  Thanks so much.

[code]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /fatfree/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* /fatfree/index.php [L,QSA]
[/code]

[code]
require_once '/app/fatfree-2.0.0/lib/base.php';

F3::route('GET /','home');
 function home() {
  echo 'Hello, world!';
 }
F3::run();

[/code]

Comment: thanks i was unable to make it work moving to another framework

Comment: @Geomorillo I think you have problem with the folder&file permission and owner.
Make sure the owner is www-data:www-data and all folders have 755 and all files have 644 permission

Comment: Actually i moved on and made my own mvc framework, but im pretty sure i checked the folder permissions and they were ok

Answer (score 2):

If you're running F3 under a subfolder, you must change the RewriteBase in .htaccess to match the folder.

Answer (score 1):

In your .htaccess you have 'index.php'  it needs a slash ...   '/index.php'

```
# Enable rewrite engine and route requests to framework
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l          
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f          
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d          
RewriteRule .* /index.php [L,QSA]
```

otherwise when it tries to rewrite /about/  it will look for /about/index.php instead of just the root /index.php

---

I just had another thought.. it 'is' possible that althought mod_rewrite is intalled there may be a quirk with the server causing it not to rewrite..

If the global route below doesnt work you might want to test the rewrite

```
RewriteRule ^/google http://www.google.com [L,NC];
```

---

You could also try a global route for the directory

```
F3::route('GET /about/*','about');
```

but that means anythin under domain.com/about/ ......  anything ...  will reroute to the about function...

---

A note about mod_rewrite and FF

As you said, FF is givikng you a 404 because it is expecting '/' instead of '/index.php'...     However, it is the index.php which is expecting the difference..

To demonstrate that, i believe you can duplicate your

```
F3::route('GET /','home');
```

as

```
F3::route('GET /index.php','home');
```

and the page should display...

The reason for this is if you just go to the / directory (or /index.php) eitehr way apache servesx the index.php page....

The mod_rewrite allows you to redirect the /about and have it redirect to the index.php..  So if your rewrite rule is not working then the redirect/rewrite does not happen and you will get a 404...

As i mentioned above, test the mod_rewrite with the google rule.. then try to go to `http://localhost:80/google`
if it does not redirect you to google then your rewrite engine is not working... (probably an issue with the windows configuration..)

---

to enable mod_rewrite under windows:
Open your http.conf
Find this line:

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

remove the comment mark (#) from the line... so you have:
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
Save the file and restart apache..

Alternatly.. I think you can just say:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

at the start of your htaccess file...

Comment: What is the address you are using to access about?   domain.com/about/index.php or domain.com/about or ?

Comment: also is that your exact htaccess file or are you using <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> ?

Comment: And also: did you check your path / route info as the manual covers: http://fatfree.sourceforge.net/ (the section titled: Can't Get the Example Running?)

Comment: Im using `http://localhost:80/about` as to the route thing... / works but /about does not, and my files are in the root directory. And yes thats my exact .htacess

Comment: If I go to `http://localhost:80/index.php I get a `404` because `index.php` expects either `/` or `/about` however only `/` works..

Comment: Did you test the rewrite with the google line i mentioned in my answer?    I take it yo uare using windows so it may be a configuration issue

Comment: Just saw you other comment...     hmm...  What setup are you using?

Comment: I'm using MAMP. So on my Mac.

Comment: Again i ask:  Did you test the rewrite with the google line i mentioned earlier?

Answer (score 1):

I banged my head on this for 2 days.  I debugged htaccess and php both.  The actual problem is this :

If you copied the .htaccess file from their fatfree-1.4.4 zip download, its not **.htaccess** its **htaccess** (. is missing)  Just rename this file to .htaccess from htaccess and everything will work perfectly as its mentioned in the document !!!

I am using this .htaccess works for non-root folders too

```
Options -Indexes 
IndexIgnore *    

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|main\.css|form\.css|favicon\.ico|robots\.txt|sitemap\.xml)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I'm using MAMP and you can't start file names with `.` on Mac OS, tried your .htaccess but no luck.

Comment: so, are u able to use .htaccess or not ? without htaccess this thing won't work. Also never worked on mac so can't really help here :(

Comment: Open Terminal, cd to the directory with htaccess in and type mv htaccess .htaccess

Answer (score 1):

> Note: If you want to call your .htaccess file something else, you can change the name of the file using the AccessFileName directive. For example, if you would rather call the file .config then you can put the following in your server configuration file:

```
AccessFileName .config
```

[here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/htaccess.html)

Answer (score 0):

This response may be too late for you but I had the same problem yesterday.

It sounds like the problem is apache is not rewriting urls.  I had the same issue when trying to get F3 running on OSX 10.7 - the '`GET /`' route would work but not the '`GET /foo`' as the F3 index.php was in a subdir for localhost/F3.  My solution was to:

1. ensure the .htaccess was set as you have.
2. ensure mod_rewrite.so was enabled in apache's httpd.conf
3. ensure that you set `AllowOverride` `All` (mine was None) for your web directory in httpd.conf (further down the file).
4. restart apache

Without step 3, apache will ignore any rewrite directives. I discovered this by changing the permalinks on a local wordpress install and they failed indicating the problem was the apache config, not F3.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running this with a MAMP stack.
I renamed their folder from "fatfree-master" to "f3".
I put that folder next to htdocs.
Their .htaccess file (now inside MAMP/f3/lib) remains untouched.

My .htaccess (in my web subfolder) is stock standard as per their example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* index.php [L,QSA]
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: It is unclear, at least to me, how this relates to the question. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Alex I'll respond once only. I found this post becasue I was having trouble getting their sample to work, as embarrassingly explained above (though it may have been useful had they included the tags, but my bad). Next, in their guide, it's not always clear to which .htaccess file they refer. So I cleared that up too. Finally they offered no MAMP/XAMP specific instruction. Hence I felt it pertinent and perhaps helpful to advise how I've deployed their framework.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and i solved it by moving the **.htaccess** file to the root directory of the fatfree project.

create a file **.htaccess** with folowing code at root directory

```
# Enable rewrite engine and route requests to framework
RewriteEngine On

# Some servers require you to specify the `RewriteBase` directive
# In such cases, it should be the path (relative to the document root)
# containing this .htaccess file
#
# RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.ini$
RewriteRule \.ini$ - [R=404]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```