# Fat-Free Framework mod rewrite doesn't work

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, document-root, fat-free-framework

I am trying to run a php project with Fat-Free Framework on MAMP, running on Yosemite 10.10.1.
I have all the project files in MAMP web root folder "htdocs" and all the fatfree project files are located within a fatfree-master dir.

The specific dir location is : htdocs/libs/FatFreeFramework/fatfree-master

I have succesfully imported a database into phpmyadmin.The size of it was 2.5mb but no errors flashed during the upload so i assume the size was not a problem at all!

I set up a virtual host on apache & now the file  httpd-vhosts.conf looks like this :

```
ServerName localhost

DocumentRoot “/Applications/MAMP/htdocs”

<Directory "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks 
    AllowOverride All 
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from All
</Directory>
```

> ErrorLog /Applications/MAMP/logs/error.log
>
> CustomLog /Applications/MAMP/logs/access.log combined

Following [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576851/simple-problem-with-mod-rewrite-in-the-fat-free-framework) instructions to enable the mod rewrite on  i edited the .htaccess file and now it looks like this :

> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteBase /libs/FatFreeFramework/fatfree-master/
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>
> RewriteRule .* /libs/FatFreeFramework/fatfree-master/index.php [L,QSA]

I modified the rewrite base to point to the /[dirname]/ and then change RewriteRule to /[dirname]/index.php

In the httpd.conf i edited the Directory to AllowOverride All but still i cannot get the project running on browser.

I noticed that there are 2 .htaccess files, one on the htdocs dir & another on fatfree-master dir!

Which one of them do i have to edit in order to enable the mod rewrite on the fatfree-framework?

Do i point correctly the path of the index.php?

Comment: don't change the path of the RewriteRule. It should simple stay index.php. The Rewritebase is used to assign the path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use this .htaccess would be fine.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.ini$
RewriteRule \.ini$ - [R=404]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Only .htaccess that matters is the one in dir that you access from browser (in your case after typing `localhost`, it should be the one in `htdocs`.

Secondly, check with `phpinfo()` function if you have **mod_rewrite** enabled. If no, enable it.

Lastly, I think you should set `RewriteBase` to `/`.

One thing you can also *try* (cause I'm not sure) is adding `Options +FollowSymLinks` right after `RewriteEngine On`

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled the mod_rewrite module on Apache?

I believe it resides in the httpd.conf file where you will need to uncomment a `LoadModule mod_rewrite` line.

Comment: Yes first i did uncomment the LoadModule mod_rewrite line & then i edited the .htaccess file.