# Trouble with F3 rerouting while using XAMPP

Tags: php, xampp, fat-free-framework

My routes.cfg:

```
GET|POST / = IndexController->index, 60
GET|POST /auth/@action = AuthController->@action
```

If I go to the url `http://localhost/powers/` it properly instantiates F3 and then reroutes to the IndexController->index as referenced above. From there it executes the following line:

```
$this->fw->reroute('/auth/login?redirect='.$path);
```

changing the url in the browser to `http://localhost/powers/auth/login?redirect=/`

Yet it fails to load with a 404. The @action is equal to 'login' which is referenced in the routes.cfg and the function login is accessible. This issue only happens when I run locally, not in production.

My .htaccess file:

```
<FilesMatch \.php\.txt$>
    RemoveHandler .php
    ForceType text/plain
</FilesMatch>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /powers/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* /powers/app/index.php [L,QSA]
```

Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: If I understand you well, the issue is not with rerouting but with `/auth/login` failing to load. Have you checked your [.htaccess](http://fatfreeframework.com/routing-engine#sample-apache-configuration), especially the `RewriteBase` directive?

Comment: I have not, I will look into that

Comment: I attempted to follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576851/simple-problem-with-mod-rewrite-in-the-fat-free-framework with no luck. I will add my .htaccess file to my question.

Comment: Don't you have a typo on the last line? Should be either `/powers/index.php` or `index.php`. Also make sure that `FilesMatch` doesn't interfere.

Comment: @xfra35 I tried that as well (even removed the `FilesMatch` just in case)

Comment: So the issue is not with rerouting but with `http://localhost/powers/auth/login` throwing a 404 right? Then for some reason, the rewriting doesn't occur, which explains that `/` is the only route working. To debug that, you'd better enable `mod_rewrite` [logging](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging). If rewriting is happening, you should see something like `internal redirect with /path/to/index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]`. If it fails, you should get a clue.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to have lead me to the solution (somethings are still not loading but at least it is not a 404). After following those steps I found out my .htaccess file was not being picked up so I had to move it to the root directory.